# ftplib python: NOOP command works in ASCII not Binary

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, ftp, no-op

I have a threaded FTP script. While the data socket is receiving the data, a threaded loop  sends NOOP commands to the control socket to keep control connection alive during large transfers.

I am prevented from using the `FTP.retrbinary()` command as, if I want to keep the control connection alive I must separate the data and control sockets which `retrbinary` does not do.

Code below:

```
def downloadFile(filename, folder):
    myhost = 'HOST'
    myuser = 'USER'
    passw = 'PASS'
    #login
    ftp = FTP(myhost,myuser,passw)

    ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
    ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    sock = ftp.transfercmd('RETR ' + filename)
    def background():
        f = open(folder + filename, 'wb')
        while True:
            block = sock.recv(1024*1024)
            if not block:
                break
            f.write(block)
        sock.close()
    t = threading.Thread(target=background)
    t.start()
    while t.is_alive():
        t.join(120)
        ftp.voidcmd('NOOP')
    ftp.quit();
```

**My PROBLEM**: `FTP.transfercmd("RETR " + filename)` defaults to ASCII transfers and Im transferring video so it has to be Binary (hence the `ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I)` call to force Binary mode).

If I ***DONT*** call `ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I)` the NOOP commands get send successfully and the output is as follows:

```
*cmd* 'NOOP'
*put* 'NOOP\r\n'
*get* '200 NOOP: data transfer in progress\n'
*resp* '200 NOOP: data transfer in progress'
*cmd* 'NOOP'
*put* 'NOOP\r\n'
*get* '200 NOOP: data transfer in progress\n'
*resp* '200 NOOP: data transfer in progress'
*cmd* 'NOOP'
*put* 'NOOP\r\n'
*get* '200 NOOP: data transfer in progress\n'
*resp* '200 NOOP: data transfer in progress'
```

etc. But the file is in ASCII and therefor corrupted. If I ***DO*** call `ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I)`, The NOOP command only sends once, and the control socket doesnt respond until the transfer completes. If the file is large, the control socket times out as if the NOOPs were never sent...

Very strange, but I am sure its simple. It seems as though the `transfercmd()` is not splitting the control and data sockets as it is supposed to... and therefore the ftp var is not seperated from the data stream... or something. strange.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Instead of using both `FTP.voidcmd(TYPE I)` and `FTP.transfercmd()`, have you tried to use `FTP.retrbinary()` instead?

Comment: @uselpa - Thanks for the response. Yes retrbinary is not an option as it does not return the data socket, which is necessary to send separate commands to the control socket.

Comment: please try `tcpdump` and/or `strace` to narrow down the problem. I'm a bit surprised to see "data transfer in progress" in response to `NOOP`, perhaps that's an `ftplib` artefact.

Comment: on an unrelated note, why do you need to keep control connection around anyway? is this a smallest test case, or is this your entire code? if it's a simple download, there are tons of other libraries, e.g. `pycurl`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545666/threaded-noop-command-during-retrbinary

Comment: @qarma - re: keeping the control connection around: Im doing it so that I can tell when the transfer is finished... otherwise ftplib will wait forever for a transfer complete response... I will look into the pseudocode you have suggested at the bottom of your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcpdump` confirms that server only sends `226 Transfer complete.` after entire file was sent by the server.

I suspect that's part of FTP specification.

In fact, look at `retrbinary` code in `ftplib.py`:

```
    self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(blocksize)
        if not data:
            break
        callback(data)
    conn.close()
    return self.voidresp()
```

The last line expects to get tranfer result (as known to server) only after tranfer is complete.

In fact it seems your code is missing `voidresp()` bit.

I am not very familiar with ftp, from what I've seen background downloaders like `lftp` actually open new control connection for each parallel download.

You have a valid concern if your file is really large.

There are many extensions to FTP, there may be something that does what you want.

Alternatively you can make a loop likes this:

```
pos = 0
while not full file:
    command REST
    download for a while in separate thread
    command ABRT
    wait for separate thread to abort
    pos += length of downloaded chunk
```

Comment: Thanks, bounty awarded, I will persist with your pseudo code solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I believe the problem is that after some time the control channel is closed, and the `226 Transfer complete` is not sent...